# Fast extraction of lines based on line numbers

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am looking for a fast way to extract lines of a file based on a list of line numbers read from a different file in bash.

Define three files:

position_file: Containing a single column of integers

full_data_file: Containing a single column of data

extracted_data_file: Containing those lines in full_data_file whose line numbers match the integers in position_file

My current way of doing this is

```
while read position; do
    awk -v pos="$position" 'NR==pos {print; exit}' < full_data_file >> extracted_data_file
done < position_file
```

The problem is that this is painfully slow and I'm trying to do this for a large number of rather large files. I was hoping someone might be able to suggest a faster way.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post sample Input_file and expected output file too in CODE TAGS in your posts.

Comment: you should execute your extraction in one go instead of wrapping your `awk` call in a `while` loop

Comment: @Aserre, I think you are right and the problem is that I keep loading the same file into memory. I'm a bit of a novice in awk and I'm not sure how I could do it in a single awk step. Could you elaborate further please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way with **`awk`** command:

Input files:

```
$ head pos.txt data.txt
==> pos.txt <==
2
4
6
8
10

==> data.txt <==
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
```

---

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }FNR in a' pos.txt data.txt > result.txt
```

---

```
$ cat result.txt
b
d
f
h
j
```

Comment: Depending how many lines of `data.txt` might be left after the last target line is printed, what percentage of lines are targeted, and assuming `pos.txt` is sorted you **might** want to try `awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]; m=$1; next } FNR in a{print; if (FNR==m) exit}' pos.txt data.txt` to see if it's faster.